# Fish shell automatic directory specific functions

Tags: fish

Is it possible to have fish automatically load additional configurations based on the directory you are in? 
A possible example, but obviously this doesn't work. You navigate to a project folder:

```
cd ~/my_proj
```

There is a file in that folder called `.fish.config` that contains a special fish function that is now accessible (since we are in `my_proj`).

Is there any built-in mechanism in fish that allows the loading from some fish config file when navigating to a directory (similar to above)?

Comment: You could use an alias to `cd`, to test the directory and run some commands depending on the current directory.

Comment: Or have a "regular" function that just returns if the pwd is not your special location, else it does the work. The tricky part in your request may just be unloading whatever was set up in the directory-specific config.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Take a look at the `--on-variable` flag for the `function` statement. You can define a function like this that runs whenever the PWD changes:

```
function react_to_pwd --on-variable PWD
   echo Reacting to PWD changing to $PWD
end
```

Comment: This is just awesome!

Answer (score 3):

There is some pre-existing work in this area:

- [direnv](https://github.com/direnv/direnv)
- [autoenv-fish](https://github.com/loopbit/autoenv_fish)
- [Automatically set environment variables based on working directory](https://github.com/fish-shell/fish-shell/issues/1765)